# Regex replace middle content of match words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to censor words by using Python regex.

My word is defined as Alphanumeric[a-zA-Z0-9] and separated by Non-Alphanumeric[^a-zA-Z0-9].

And the words should be censored by inner characters are replaced by * and others remain the same.

Ex:

```
test=y
tes't
test'
test-y
tes-ty
    test  Test    
test
abcdefg  Test ... test are the best... some thing words @@$: HAHA TEST ONE REAL PLAYER!!! EXCELLENT! It's testy night
```

Result should be

```
t**t=y
tes't
t**t'
t**t-y
tes-ty
    t**t  T**t    
t**t
abcdefg  T**t ... test are the best... some thing words @@$: HAHA T**T ONE REAL PLAYER!!! EXCELLENT! It's testy night
```

I have tried to use the regex to do it.
I use re module in python3.

1.I try to match the pattern.

2.Capture the group in matched pattern without the censored word.

3.Try to concat the groups with the word.

For example:
  I tried to censor the word 'test'.

Since I don't how to replace it with *, I try to replace with 'SUB' to see my pattern is right or not first.

```
inputStr = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-z0-9]+)test([^a-zA-z0-9]+)', r'\1SUB\2', inputStr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
inputStr = re.sub(r'^test([^a-zA-z0-9]+)', r'SUB\1', inputStr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
replacedStr = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-z0-9]+)test$', r'\1SUB', inputStr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(replacedStr)
```

Also, is it possible to use one line to do above thing, I don't know how to use the group in one-line pattern.

```
replacedStr = re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9]+test[^a-zA-z0-9]+|^test[^a-zA-z0-9]+|[^a-zA-z0-9]+test$', 'SUB', inputStr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

But it doesn't work well.

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9]+test[^a-zA-z0-9]+|^test[^a-zA-z0-9]+|[^a-zA-z0-9]+test$', 'SUB', inputStr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

My Result

```
SUB=y
tes't
SUB'
test-y
tes-ty
    SUB  Test    
SUB
abcdefg  SUB ... test are the best... some thing words @@$: HAHA SUB ONE REAL PLAYER!!! EXCELLENT! It's testy night
```

I see my pattern somewhat doesn't match some 'test' and I don't know why.
https://regexr.com/3nk9l

So, my questions are

1.What is wrong with my pattern?

2.How to let the matched word be replaced with * in its inner?

Thx

Comment: I think there is a non regex solution to this that would be much easier.  Maybe use a dictionary of censored words, and the value is their censored version?

Comment: But what I need is match any case combination, ex: Test, TEsT, tEsT, test, will be converted into T**t, T**T, t**T, t**t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that rather than explicitly match for `^test`, `^test$` and `test$` (which is where I think your regex is falling down) you might do better using [look ahead and behind assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to separate the words then do the replacement of the inner letters.

```
import re

for line in """test=y
tes't
test'
test-y
tes-ty
    test  Test
test
abcdefg  Test ... test are the best... some thing words @@$: HAHA TEST ONE REAL PLAYER!!! EXCELLENT! It's testy night
""".splitlines():
    print line

    print re.sub(r'(?<!{0})(t)es(t)(?!{0})'.format(r'[a-zA-z0-9]'), r'\1**\2', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Results in:

```
test=y
t**t=y
tes't
tes't
test'
t**t'
test-y
t**t-y
tes-ty
tes-ty
    test  Test
    t**t  T**t
test
t**t
abcdefg  Test ... test are the best... some thing words @@$: HAHA TEST ONE REAL PLAYER!!! EXCELLENT! It's testy night
abcdefg  T**t ... t**t are the best... some thing words @@$: HAHA T**T ONE REAL 
PLAYER!!! EXCELLENT! It's testy night
```

Comment: Gee one has to be quick on stack overflow ! :)

Comment: The `+` (one or more) modifiers in your original regex are consuming characters that then are not available to match word boundaries. Even removing them will still give a problem with `test test`. Does the space terminate the first word or start the second word. You need it to do both, hence the look ahead/behind functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])(t)es(t)(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```

and replace by this:

```
\1**\2
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/yZjFuA):

```
import re 
regex = r"(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])(t)es(t)(?![a-zA-Z0-9])"
subst = "\\1**\\2"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, inputStr, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```